how to move the label in text field in flutter?
hi i have a text field that is for content . so it should have bigger space.
but my problem is the label - text i used in this text field . is in the center . and i don't  like it at all .
i want to be at the start of box :(
like this:

this is my code too:
 TextField(
              maxLines: 10,
              controller: _content,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start,
                labelText: 'Content',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
              ),


You can try adding alignLabelWithHint: true to InputDecoration.

You just need to set alignLabelWithHint to true

TextField(
              maxLines: 10,
             
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start,
                alignLabelWithHint: true,
                labelText: 'Content',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
              ),)

for more info here
